# R: Check which branch of a package was installed with install_git

Tags: r, git, devtools

Say I use the function install_git from library devtools to install a particular branch of a package e.g. from the install_git documentation:

```
install_git("git://github.com/hadley/stringr.git", branch = "stringr-0.2")
```

Is there a way later on to find out if a branch was installed and if so which one? I can use packageVersion() to find the version of the package installed, but this does not give me any additional information about branches referenced.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer - the information is contained in the output of the function packageDescription('package_name') e.g.

```
 packageDescription('mlr')
```

The output is fairly verbose, but the following items within that output hold the answer:

```
RemoteRepo: mlr
RemoteRef: mindepth_order
GithubRepo: mlr
GithubRef: mindepth_order
```

This shows that package mlr is loaded, referencing the branch mindepth_order.